# Does it make sense to use a dictionary over creating an instance to store a players score?

Tags: python

I have a game where only one player can play at a time. I am creating a class and initiating it once in game then when a new game is started I will delete and create a new instance.

```
class CurrentGameScore:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bet_list = []
        self.score = 0
        self.wins = 0
```

But I was thinking for faster access times to these variables would it be better to use a dictionary or I was thinking of  an instance with the dictionary and create a new one every time a new game starts?

```
dict = {'bet_list': [],
        'score': 0,
        'wins': 0 }

class CurrentGameScore:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = {'bet_list': [],
                     'score': 0,
                     'wins': 0}
```

The `bet_list` will have games added to it and cleared once that round of games has finished and  the score/ wins will be updated.

I am looking into MongoDB to store the players score at the end of each game and this will be printed to the player to see previous scores. So I am not sure if this means I will need to have an instance when pulling the data from the database?

I am just looking for suggestions or pointers to the best approach :)

Comment: You can absolutely use dictionaries for this approach until and unless you're gonna access this data in multiple files AND number of properties are less.

Comment: I will be only printing it to the player in the PYQT app I am building I do not plan on using the leader board anywhere else. So the dictionary approach seems like a good idea just for faster access times

Comment: Yes, so you can go ahead with it.